# Dynamic Columns and Grouping in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

maybe you can help me with my problem: While I found various ways, links and how-tos for either dynamic columns or  grouping, I did not find a way to combine them.
I will further explain my project´s goal:
I want to display informations about something like a sports competition with a DataGrid. Imagine an event, where multiple players play different sports and end up with results, so my datagrid headers would look something like:

Sport|Player|TeeNumber|Game X|Game Y|Game Z|...

My data source provides me with a list of Results{Sport, Player, TeeNumber, GameNumber, Result} from which I generate a List of PlayerResults{Sport, Player, TeeNumber {GameNumber, Result}}

Now I want to display a configurable Number of Results for a Game, which I have also done already via a DataTable, where I add the Columns in Code-Behind.
How do I realise grouping by Sport, preferably Expander-like, now ?

PS: The Game Numbers do not vary over different sports and there is just either one or no Result for a given combination of Sport, Player and GameNumber

Edit: Now with some fiddling and the simple idea that a DataTable´s Default View is of type List, which is enough for a CollectionView to be usable, I got my basic project idea accomplished.

Ok, my Model gives me back a List of these:

```
public class GameValue
{
    public string Sport;
    public string Player;
    public string TeeNumber;
    public string GameNumber;
    public string GameResult;
    public DateTime GameDate;
}
```

which I convert to different ObservableCollections in my ViewModel, namely Games and PlayerResults which are based on these classes, which inherit my ObservableObject class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Game : ObservableObject
    {
    private string mGameNumber;
    private DateTime mGameDate;

    public string GameNumber
    {
        get { return mGameNumber; }
        set
        {
            mGameNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("GameNumber");
        }
    }

    public DateTime GameDate
    {
        get { return mGameDate; }
        set
        {
            mGameDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("GameDate");
        }
    }
}
```

and my PlayerResult class:

```
public class PlayerResult: Player
{
    private ObservableCollection<GameResult> mGameResults;

    public ObservableCollection<GameResult> GameResults
    {
        get { return mGameResults; }
        set
        {
            mGameResults = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("GameResults");
        }
    }

    public PlayerResult (List<GameResult> pGameResults, Player pPlayer )
    {
        Name = pPlayer.Name;
        TeeNumber = pPlayer.TeeNumber;
        Sport = pPlayer.Sport;
        GameResults = new ObservableCollection<GameResult>(pGameResults);

    }


    public String ContainsResultForGame(string mGameNumber)
    {

        var tmpResults = GameResults.Where(p => p.GameNumber == mGameNumber);
        if (tmpResults.FirstOrDefault() == null)
            return "";
        return tmpResults.First().GameNumber;
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel´s constructor I first get my Models Data and convert it. After that, I fill my DataTable
ViewModel

```
public  MainViewModel()
{
    FetchModelData();
    FillDataTable();
}

private void FillDataTable()
{
    PlayerTable.Clear();

    PlayerTable.Columns.Add("Sport");
    PlayerTable.Columns.Add("Player");
    PlayerTable.Columns.Add("TeeNumber");

    for (int i = 1; i <= GamesShown; i++)
    {
        PlayerTable.Columns.Add(Games.ElementAt(i - 1).GameNumber);
    }

    foreach (var pResult in PlayerResults)
    {
        var tmpResult = pResult;
        var tmpRow = new string[3 + GamesShown];
        tmpRow[0] = tmpResult.Sport;
        tmpRow[1] = tmpResult.Name;
        tmpRow[2] = tmpResult.TeeNumber;
        for (int i = 0; i < GamesShown; i++)
        {
            tmpRow[3 + i] = tmpResult.ContainsResultForGame(Games[i].GameNumber);

        }
        PlayerTable.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

    }
}
```

GamesShown is a simple int value indicating, how many games I want to display, in this case 5 as some starting point.

My View gets it DataContext from Codebehind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

and here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WFP_Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Window.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsPlayerResults" Source="{Binding PlayerTable}" >
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Sport"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="TableauGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPlayerResults}}">
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Sport}"/>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

New Question: How can I change the Groupstyle, so that the "Sport" is shown right next to the expander, if the expander is enabled?

For a sample, I can PM you the link to my google code project(wanted to be able to work from different computers on it)

Comment: Show your code and we might be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: @Sheridan Added imho the important parts of my code. If you need more, feel free to add another comment etc. Thanks in advance.